# inconsistency in showing disk label

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, gpt

I've got my new laptop (thinkpad 440p) with windows 7.1 pre-installed and wanted to have single-boot ubuntu 14.04 on it. I wanted to change the disk partition table to "msdos" (legacy), so I change boot startup setting to just legacy and using bootable ubuntu usb disk then used "parted" to change the table.

```
sudo parted /dev/sda/
mklabel msdos
mktable msdos
```

the first problem is that when I check it with gparted it shows this disk as unallocated with no partition table. Also when I run:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

sometimes I get this message:

**"Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table"**

but sometimes it doesn't show the same error.

any try to install ubuntu will end up having an infinte pause and error on not being able to format partition in SCSI (0,0,0).

What do you suggest in this case to make it possible to install Ubuntu? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The gpt tag and versioning in your question indicates it may have been Windows 8.1 and not 7 as listed in your question. Am I correct?

Comment: I suggest that you use gdisk to edit gpt partition tables.

Comment: no as it comes with preinstalled OS you cannot do this and even If you succeed you will face many problems you should have chosen a free dos machine instead